# How to define custom parse exception, which holds data?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to define custom file parse exception class, which to holds information - the name of the file and the line of the file on which the exception is happening.

```
class FileParseException : Exception {
    string fileName;
    long lineNumber;
    public FileParseException() {
    }
    public string GetFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public long GetLineNumber() {
        return lineNumber;
    }
}
```

How should I store the data for the current file and when it rises an exception to access it through thy-catch block:

```
try {
    // some code here
}
catch (FileParseException fpe) {
    Console.WriteLine(fpe.getLineNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, C# has properties, so you should use them, not create `GetXXX` methods. In your case, public automatic properties with private setters should do the job:

```
public string FileName { get; private set; }
public long LineNumber { get; private set; }
```

You can set them in a constructor of the exception:

```
public FileParseException(string fileName, long lineNumber)
{
    FileName = fileName;
    LineNumber = lineNumber;
}
```

To throw such exception, use the constructor above:

```
throw new FileParseException(fileName, lineNumber);
```

And when you catch it, you can access the properties:

```
catch (FileParseException fpe)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Error in file {0} on line {1}.", fpe.FileName, fpe.LineNumber);
}
```

Also, you should probably set the `Message` of the exception, by passing the message to the base constructor:

```
public FileParseException(string fileName, long lineNumber)
    : base(
        string.Format(
            "Error while parsing file {0} on line {1}.", fileName, lineNumber))
{
    FileName = fileName;
    LineNumber = lineNumber;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the properties uninitialized when the base constructor is called?

Comment: @jgauffin, if you mean what I had in the call to `base()`, then you're right. It was a copy-paste error and it's fixed now.

Comment: Yep, that was what I meant. gr8.